# ASP.NET site search string in other website

Tags: c#, asp.net, search-engine

I have a website with products part number in it. I want to know if it is possible to search this part number in other website search box. That means to insert the string to the other website search box and execute searching all by code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admitting you're not the owner of the other website and you don't know how it works :
When you click to the "Search" button of the other website, it triggers a request against the webserver : something like a GET or POST, or maybe the same but through an Ajax request.

It depends of the targeted website, but the best thing to do is probably to get the information about this GET or POST (very easy with Firefox or Google in the Network tab) and to process it yourself from your own application's code using an [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (for example).

This approach is easier and safer than to try to mimic the "Fill the textbox and click on the button and retrieve the response" action, but this is possible too (with web testing frameworks for example : watin, selenium...)

Concretely :

- Go to the website you want to dig in
- Open "Net" tab of your google chrome / firefox / whatever you want, enable it
- Fill the search textbox
- Click the search button
- Look at the request and response appeared in the browser : you will know how to send a "search" query and the format of the answer returned.

This is general advices, not a definitive answer, because you don't provide enough details to help you more, but I hope this will be helpful !